How to create a synchronous Kafka Queue for booking?
I'm trying to create (paper) a system architecture for a booking system that need to handle a lot of req/sec.
My idea will be to use Kafka for take care about the queue and priority but seems that I can use for async task.
I'm struggling to understand how I can implement the "red back arrow". Will be possible or I need to totally reshape my architecture?

Look at an orchestrator-based solution that allows solving such problems seamlessly.

Is the problem unique to Kafka?
If you write to a database from a service, how do you ensure it had been durably written?
The general solution is a Saga Pattern.

The "LB" (and following services) would either

Store and Return an ID when receiving and forwarding a request, and be able to lookup the status of this ID when requested. Kafka doesn't do this; it only returns an optional "ack" that the message was received and, optionally, replicated.

It is then the responsibility of the upstream client to poll this status from where the record is stored.
You may need multiple databases to implement this.


Use distinct request/reply topics. Have upstream services push you any updates, and have the client dual-function as a receiving server.


Not shown in the diagram is an actual Kafka cluster; it has a balancing algorithm built-in, not on load.
Most databases have a Kafka Connect sink connector, or you can look into change-data-capture if it meets your needs.

Or, as mentioned in the comments, you can use an ochestration service.
I have no affiliation with the following.

https://temporal.io/
https://www.littlehorse.io/


You don’t need to completely reshape your architecture. Instead, you can combine Kafka for the asynchronous part and another system for handling synchronous interactions.
